# $\sum_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{5/2}}$ and Cauchy condesation test

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove that this series converges? I use cauchy condensation test but there is a problem because an is not non-increasing for $n=1,n=2$ .Should another test be used? 
$$\sum_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{5/2}}$$

Comment: The only thing that matters is the tail of a series. As long as a convergence test works for the tail, it works for the whole series.

Comment: so being non-increasing from (random example) $n>5$ it doesnt matter ?

Comment: Nope. I hope my answer shows why this is.

Answer (score 2):

Try this tes: you have that $ln(n)<\sqrt{n}<$ for n>=1, and from that your series is 
< than convergent series $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$=> your series is cconvergent

Comment: $ln(n)<n$ would work too ?

Comment: yes, of course...

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $\frac{\log(n)}{n^{5/2}}$ decreases for $n\ge3$, then we can look at
$$
\frac{\log(1)}{1^{5/2}}+\frac{\log(2)}{2^{5/2}}+\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{\log(n)}{n^{5/2}}
$$
The first two terms are just numbers. Apply the test to the slightly smaller infinite sum.

Comment: cauchy series should start from zero ?

Comment: Doesn't need to. If it really bothers you, you could look at the sum as $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\log(n+3)}{(n+3)^{5/2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\ln(n)=_\infty o(n^\alpha),\quad\forall \alpha>0$$
and we can prove it using the L'Hôpital's rule.

Now we have

$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{5/2}}=_\infty o\left(\frac{n^\alpha}{n^{5/2}}\right)=_\infty o\left(\frac{1}{n^{5/2-\alpha}}\right)$$
so it suffices to choose $\alpha>0$ such that $\frac52-\alpha>1$ and use the asymptotic comparison to conclude.